# systemctl start httpd command not failing with error code

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I am having a problem to run this code.

```
#systemctl start httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor prese                           t: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-01-17 17:59:46 UTC; 20s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2188 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAIL                           URE)
  Process: 2187 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, st                           atus=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2187 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 17 17:59:45 hackdays httpd[2187]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072...0
Jan 17 17:59:45 hackdays httpd[2187]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072...0
Jan 17 17:59:45 hackdays httpd[2187]: no listening sockets available, shu...n
Jan 17 17:59:45 hackdays httpd[2187]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 17 17:59:46 hackdays systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, ...E
Jan 17 17:59:46 hackdays kill[2188]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 17 17:59:46 hackdays systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exite...1
Jan 17 17:59:46 hackdays systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 17 17:59:46 hackdays systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 17 17:59:46 hackdays systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Try `sudo` in front of that command - those errors may be related to permission failure. I agree this is off topic. Please also do not beg for urgency anywhere on the internet, including here.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

From the stacktrace  I can see the below

> Address already in use:

Can you check if the port is been used already by some other process.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. but honestly, i havent liked your reply @halfer
i am not a kid, i accept my mistake that i have not read what can i post or what i can not. but u should not repeat one line 1000 times. this is really insulting. 
dont need your help... not a mongo !